# Delete all documents with a certain property value?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to delete all documents where a certain property has a certain value. The code below is my best attempt, but the ES API returns a parse error:

```
const userProperty = "couchDbOrigin";

client.deleteByQuery({
    index: "_all",
    body: { query: { bool: { must: [{ terms: { [userProperty]: user } }] } } }
});
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: add erro in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) expect criteria as an array :

so you should use :

```
client.deleteByQuery({
    index: "_all",
    body: { query: { bool: { must: [{ terms: { [userProperty]: [user] } }] } } }
});
```

But if you delete document for one user at a time, you should use a [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) that expects a single value and can perform better

```
client.deleteByQuery({
        index: "_all",
        body: { query: { bool: { must: [{ term: { [userProperty]: user } }] } } }
    });
```